# WP_Query meta_query where meta value ends in space

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm running a standard WP_Query on a property website, and I want to find all properties that have a postcode beginning with 'SC1'. In the meta query, doing a normal LIKE on the postcode works, but it also returns properties with postcode SC13, which isn't what I want.

As a result, I've changed my meta query to be as follows:

```
array(
    'key'     => '_address_postcode',
    'value'   => 'SC1 ', // Notice the addition of the space
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
```

However.. it's not working. I've dug deeper and it seems that WordPress is trimming the values:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/af69f4ab1a0b44594b1f231c183f7a533575a893/wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php#L597

Any idea how I can search for meta values that specifically have a space at the end? I thought of doing something like so:

```
array(
    'key'     => '_address_postcode',
    'value'   => 'SC1 %',// Add a space then wildcard
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
```

... but that doesn't work. Can anyone think of a way to get around this :-S

Comment: Can I ask why do you have such kind of value and if the last space is really meaningful for the meta value? I don't think so.

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear?  You say you want to return properties that start with sc1 but then it gives you sc1(3) which starts with sc1.  What exactly are you looking for in your search?

Comment: To be absolutely clear SC1 and SC13 are completely different postcodes in completely different areas. Imagine I have a page wehere I want to just show properties with a postcode that start with SC1. That's when I'd want to search postcodes beginning with 'SC1 ' (with space on end). I don't know how to make that any more clearer.

Comment: As far I undersntand, you don't need of the extra space in the query to do that. Anyway, you have a interesting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note sure how your structure is, but here's one way, using `RLIKE` comparison and a *space* [character class](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/#character-classes):

```
array(
    'key'     => '_address_postcode',
    'value'   => '^SC1[[:space:]]',    // Starts with 'SC1 '  
    'compare' => 'RLIKE'
)
```

Maybe you should consider adjusting the meta values, as suggested by @cybmeta?

But note that meta queries can be slow, so alternatives might be better here (e.g. as a custom taxonomy?).

Comment: Do you have evidence of this working? It's not working for me for some reason. Also, I can't find [:space:] mentioned anywhere on the web. Any links to resources would be great.

Comment: I use MariaDB, so I linked to their KB. There was also a typo that I fixed . @BIOSTALL

Answer (score -1):

You can use `&nbsp;` in your meta query.

```
array(
    'key'     => '_address_postcode',
    'value'   => 'SC1&nbsp;',
    'compare' => 'RLIKE'
)
```

Comment: Do you have evidence of this working? It's not working for me, and surely that would search for the actual string '&nbsp;'?